# Presto SQL: TO_UNIXTIME

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to convert a readable timestamp to UNIX time in Amazon Athena (Presto).

For example: I want to convert `2018-08-24 18:42:16` to `1535136136000`.

Here is my syntax:

```
    TO_UNIXTIME('2018-08-24 06:42:16') new_year_ut
```

My error is:

```
   SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:77: Unexpected parameters (varchar(19)) for function to_unixtime. Expected: to_unixtime(timestamp) , to_unixtime(timestamp with time zone)
```

Comment: FYI:  Presto SQL is now Trino

Answer (score 3):

you need to cast the string `'2018-08-24 06:42:16'` to one of the allowed types

```
TO_UNIXTIME(cast ('2018-08-24 06:42:16' as timestamp) ) new_year_ut
```

or

```
TO_UNIXTIME( timestamp '2018-08-24 06:42:16' )
```